# How to Use BSP Library in a Project?

Tags: embedded, hal, stm32f7, bsp

I'd like to create a program by which I can record and listen sound by using my board, STM32F746G-Disco. I'd like to use BSP library, however, I have some questions.

When I looked at the stm32746g_discovery_audio.c file, I saw that there are 2 global variables named **haudio_out_sai** and **haudio_in_sai**, and there are some functions that configures these sai components. Then do I need to **enable** and **configure** SAI components in **CubeMX**? Because in the documentation of the library, it is said that the functions configure the related components about the audio, but these functions don't take any SAI parameters so I cannot initialize them with the variables that CubeMX defines.

Comment: Do you start with empty project with only empty main.c? Or what is your starting point?

Comment: I will need to use XCUBEAI so I don't want to start with an empty project. Now I created a C project. My friends said that I need to enable everything involved in the program as a formality. I did that but I have still a problem as I mentioned in the other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72672842/program-is-unable-to-exit-from-interrupt-function?noredirect=1#comment128490781_72672842).